# GtkDrawingArea gets messed up when resized

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk, python-vlc

I'm working on a `GTK+` frontend for `libvlc` in `python` using `python-vlc`. So far I followed [this guide](https://www.codementor.io/princerapa/python-media-player-vlc-gtk-favehuy2b), which is working fine, except that when I resize the window, the `DrawingArea` gets messed up as you can see in the picture (there's probably a word for that phenomenon I don't know).

---

[image: Messed up GtkDrawingArea]

---

I'm getting these warnings in the console, but am not sure if this is related:

```
[00007fce1c014eb0] main filter error: Failed to create video converter
[00007fce2807ff70] vdpau_avcodec generic error: Xlib is required for VDPAU
```

I already tried setting the background color of the window using the `css` styling for `GTK+` but it had no effect.

I think this should not happen, am I missing something? I'm on `wayland` by the way.

Comment: you should rather draw black rectangle to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Google and checking different examples I created code which fills background in `DrawingArea` with black color.

Assign drawing function to `DrawingArea`

```
self.draw_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
self.draw_area.connect("draw", self.da_draw_event)
```

Function which fills area

```
def da_draw_event(self, widget, cairo_ctx):
    cairo_ctx.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
    cairo_ctx.paint()
```

---

Full code

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
gi.require_version('GdkX11', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GdkX11

import vlc

MRL = ""

class ApplicationWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Python-Vlc Media Player")
        self.player_paused=False
        self.is_player_active = False
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

    def show(self):
        self.show_all()

    def setup_objects_and_events(self):
        self.playback_button = Gtk.Button()
        self.stop_button = Gtk.Button()

        self.play_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-play",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )
        self.pause_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-pause",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )
        self.stop_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-stop",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )

        self.playback_button.set_image(self.play_image)
        self.stop_button.set_image(self.stop_image)

        self.playback_button.connect("clicked", self.toggle_player_playback)
        self.stop_button.connect("clicked", self.stop_player)

        self.draw_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.draw_area.set_size_request(300, 300)
        self.draw_area.connect("realize",self._realized)
        self.draw_area.connect("draw", self.da_draw_event)

        self.hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.playback_button, True, True, 0)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.stop_button, True, True, 0)

        self.vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.add(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.draw_area, True, True, 0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox, False, False, 0)

    def da_draw_event(self, widget, cairo_ctx):
        #print('da_draw_event')
        #print('widget:', widget)
        #print('cairo_ctx:', cairo_ctx)

        cairo_ctx.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
        cairo_ctx.paint()

    def stop_player(self, widget, data=None):
        self.player.stop()
        self.is_player_active = False
        self.playback_button.set_image(self.play_image)

    def toggle_player_playback(self, widget, data=None):

        """
        Handler for Player's Playback Button (Play/Pause).
        """

        if self.is_player_active == False and self.player_paused == False:
            self.player.play()
            self.playback_button.set_image(self.pause_image)
            self.is_player_active = True

        elif self.is_player_active == True and self.player_paused == True:
            self.player.play()
            self.playback_button.set_image(self.pause_image)
            self.player_paused = False

        elif self.is_player_active == True and self.player_paused == False:
            self.player.pause()
            self.playback_button.set_image(self.play_image)
            self.player_paused = True
        else:
            pass

    def _realized(self, widget, data=None):
        self.vlcInstance = vlc.Instance("--no-xlib")
        self.player = self.vlcInstance.media_player_new()
        win_id = widget.get_window().get_xid()
        self.player.set_xwindow(win_id)
        self.player.set_mrl(MRL)
        self.player.play()
        self.playback_button.set_image(self.pause_image)
        self.is_player_active = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not sys.argv[1:]:
       print("Exiting \nMust provide the MRL.")
       sys.exit(1)
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 1:
        MRL = sys.argv[1]
        window = ApplicationWindow()
        window.setup_objects_and_events()
        window.show()
        Gtk.main()
        window.player.stop()
        window.vlcInstance.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @furas pointed out in the comments, constantly drawing a black rectangle on the `DrawingArea` works very well. I use the following code inside a `widget` that derives from `Gtk.DrawingArea`:

```py
def draw(self, c, *args):
    rect = self.get_allocation()
    win = self.get_window().get_position()
    c.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
    c.rectangle(rect.x - win.x, rect.y - win.y, rect.width, rect.height)
    c.fill()
self.connect("draw", draw)
```

Edit: See @furas answer for an even simpler approach.